# How to run a script to leave domain with systemd right before shutdown?

Tags: systemd, dbus, systemctl

Right before shutdown I would like to run a script that unjoins (leaves) an instance from our domain on shutdown.

I have this as the .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to remove domain join
After=network-online.target sssd.service realmd.service dbus.service dbus.socket

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/tmp/autoDomainLeave.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target
```

My script basically gets the service account details from AWS secrets store and then run the command:

```
echo $Password | real leave --verbose --user=$Username network.et
```

I have added some be-dugging in my script and this is the error message I am getting:

```
realm: Couldn't connect to realm service:
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.realmd:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.ShuttingDown:
Refusing activation, D-Bus is shutting down."
```

I have read all the documentation, but just don't get it and not able to get it to work - can anyone help?

Thanks! Nik